# JavaScript, SVG clippath not displaying properly after attribute change

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, clip-path

I have an SVG-based graph. On top is a scrollable area, where the user can navigate around the graph, as shown in the image:

[image: Scroll Area]

By dragging either of the tabs on the left/right, the user can zoom in on a particular part of the plot, as shown in the image:

[image: Scrolled]

Notice that only the *selected* portion of the graph is blue, and has a grey highlight. Both the blue and the highlight are unchanged, but are clipped using a clipping mask:

```
<clippath id="clip_path_scroll">
  <rect id="clip_path_scroll_rect" x="x" y="y" width="w" height="h" stroke-width="0" />
</clippath>
```

and

```
<g clip-path="url(#clip_path_scroll)">
  <rect id="highlighted" width="w" height="h" x="x" y="y" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)" stroke="none" />
  <path id="blue_plot" d="..." stroke="rgba(26, 171, 219, 1)" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</g>
```

And this all works fine and dandy. The clip path works flawlessly, when dragging the tabs. In that situation, it is changed incrementally, as the tab(s) slide.

But I have a reset button, that calls the following:

```
$('#left_scroll_group').attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
$('#right_scroll_group').attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
$('#clip_path_scroll_rect').attr('width', width).attr('x', x);
```

and when this runs, the outcome is the following:

[image: Post-Reset]

Notice that the tab groups snap back to exactly where they should be, but it appears the clip path has only partially gone back to its original width and x-position.

**BUT THIS ISN'T THE CASE**

If I view the page source, and hover over the clippath `rect` object, it shows the following:

[image: Clip Path Rect]

That is to say, it shows the `rect` object DID resize and move to its original position, but is not displaying properly. Moving either of the tabs *immediately* snaps the clippath back to working properly, as in the first two images.

Why is this happening? It happens whether the right tab is moved, or the left, or both. If the tabs are moved only a little, there doesn't seem to be much issue, but the obvious glitch/error increases as the tabs are moved further.

A similar function performs the same `attr` changes to the clippath, but it *always* shortens the path length. This glitch only seems to be happening when lengthening the length.

I am using the same types of operations on many other elements in the graph, and all work fine. All are referenced with jQuery notation (i.e. `$('#element')`).

*I am not interested in using d3 or other libraries. I am looking for jQuery or pure JS solutions only.*

**EDIT 1**

I've also tried

```
var steps = Math.floor(scrollPlotWidth - $('#clip_path_scroll_rect').attr('width'));
var curWidth = Math.ceil($('#clip_path_scroll_rect').attr('width'));
var curX = $('#clip_path_scroll_rect').attr('x');

for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++){
    $('#clip_path_scroll_rect').attr('x', curX).attr('width', curWidth);
    curX--;
    curWidth++;
}
```

With no success. The changes are happening incrementally, but still no dice - it looks the same as before. This clipping issue is only happening in Safari, and seems to be fine in FireFox. Haven't tested others.

**WORKING SOLUTION (HACKED)**

When defining the `rect` within the clippath, I changed the width property. I've changed it from what is shown above to the following:

```
<rect id="highlighted" style="width:w;" height="h" x="x" y="y" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)" stroke="none" />
```

And then, the clippath functionality works properly IFF I apply the two operations:

```
$('#clip_path_scroll_rect').attr('x', x).css('width', w);

$('#clip_path_scroll_rect').animate(
    {"width": w},
    {duration: 1,
    step: function(){
        this.setAttribute("x", x);
    }
});
```

Removing either of these will prevent it from working. I'm not sure why, but it will have to be a temporary fix until something better comes along. Answers are still very much welcome!

Comment: What browser are you testing on?  Is it just happening on that one?  As a workaround, you might try reattaching the clip path. Ie. `gElem.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip_path_scroll)");`

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yeah you're right about the browser thing - I've been testing in Safari. It works like a treat in FireFox, and I'm having issues in Chrome, but suspect I just need to upload it to the server for that one. As for the reattaching, I've tried 1) renaming the clippath, and then 2) changing the clippath in the `g` tag to the new name. Still no dice.

Comment: @Birrel Did you ever find a solution / bug report for this on Chrome? I'm running into the same issue on Webkit browsers.

Comment: @Jamie no I did not. I hat to put that script on the back-burner while wrapping up something else, and so haven't been able to look at it much since then. I do 99% of my pre-cross-browser testing in Safari, which is likely where my issues were coming from.

Comment: I found a (hacky) solution by changing the ID of the clipPath element (and also updating the references) every time you render. In my case I just appended the new width to the ID.

Comment: Can you simply wrap your svg into a `<div>` with `overflow: hidden` ?